# What language for a Web Chat?

Tags: ajax, language-agnostic, facebook, twitter, chat

I need to create a simple web chat ( like facebook chat )

What language do I need to use ( server-side ) ?

Erlang ? PHP ? Python ? Ruby ? ecc

Are there any examples ?

Thanks  ^_^

Comment: the implementation of facebook's chat system is anything but "simple"

Comment: for scale like facebook it has to be simple otherwise it will not work, where u found that their system is complex?

Comment: I remember reading a blog post from facebook developers saying they used a combination of erlang, c++, comet javascript and php.

Answer (score 3):

Most web-based chat apps I've seen are a combination of server-side code (of various flavors) and client-side javascript.  On balance I'd say it doesn't matter what you use on the server side, go with what you know.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/). It is server-side javascript, so it's easier to communicate with client-side javascript.

As a matter of fact, they have a [chat demo here](http://chat.nodejs.org/) along with the [source code](http://github.com/ry/node_chat/tree/master).

Node.js is MADE for this type of thing. I'd recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you can use any language you want on the server side, just like any other programming exercise. Really.

You'll save yourself a lot of time and headaches if you use something that's already been written, though. XMPP (and any decent XMPP server) has a [web interface built in to the protocol](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html), and any decent server implements it.

On the client, I use a JavaScript library called [Strophe](http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/) to connect. There's also [JSJaC](http://blog.jwchat.org/jsjac/), extracted from a pre-built open-source web chat client called [JWChat](http://blog.jwchat.org/jwchat/).

This should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Actually for the best UI you can use Silverlight, by using the power of mighty .NET. It's C# you know.

Comment: Right, because silverlight has a huge install base.

Comment: it's not that subjective after all.

Comment: yes, with its huge ui capabilities SL is the best.

Comment: First of all, he's asking for a server side language. Second of all, silverlight is a terrible idea even for the client side. Javascript is probably the best option, but even flash is better than silverlight. Silverlight does not have a big enough userbase, and isn't *reliably* implemented cross-platform, so it would not be a wise choice.

Comment: When some one talks about web it mean open standard Web